# Python Update Dictionary Key with Dictionary Values

Tags: python, dictionary

If you have a Dictionary like so:

```
{"key1":{"month":"2017-01","randomNumber":32}}
```

is there a way to add/update `key1` with the following:

```
{"month":"2017-02","randomNumber":12}
```

such that the result would be a dictionary of dictionaries with an output as follows:

```
{"key1":{"month":"2017-01","randomNumber":32},{"month":"2017-02","randomNumber":12}}
```

Everything I've tried results in the nested dictionary as the value is being overwritten each time instead of having the new dictionary appended to the previous value so the output is:

```
{"key1":{"month":"2017-02","randomNumber":12}}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

a code example:

```
theKeys = ['key1','key2','key3']
sDate = "2017-01-01"
eDate = "2017-12-31"
data = defaultdict(dict)
for aKey in theKeys:
    for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, dtstart=sDate, until=eDate):
        year = dt.strftime("%Y")
        month = dt.strftime("%m")
        daysInMonth = str(monthrange(int(year),int(dt.strftime("%m")))[1])
        firstDateMonth = year + "-" + month + "-" "1"
        lastDateMonth = year + "-" + month + "-" + daysInMonth  

        dataResults = {}
        dataResults["month"] = year + "-" + month
        dataResults["randomNumber"] = randint(1, 100)

        data[aKey].update(dataResults)
```

Comment: you have to create list or dict for this to get output: ex. {"key1":{{"month":"2017-01","randomNumber":32},{"month":"2017-02","randomNumber":12} }} or use list ```[{"month":"2017-01","randomNumber":32},{"month":"2017-02","randomNumber":12} ]}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of the key as a list and append new elements to the list

```
K = {"key1":[{"month":"2017-01","randomNumber":32},{"month":"2017-02","randomNumber":12}]}
K['key1'].append({"month":"2017-03","randomNumber":42})
```

Result:

```
{'key1': [{'randomNumber': 32, 'month': '2017-01'}, {'randomNumber': 12, 'month': '2017-02'}, {'randomNumber': 42, 'month': '2017-03'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.... I've tried that, but then the output is {'key1':[{... and I need the output to be {'key1':{... Do I just need to leave it as a list and modify the print output or perform some other transformation after I get the list of dictionaries fully populated?

Comment: Yes you can modify the print output statement as per your requirement. and just an fyi {"key1":{"month":"2017-01","randomNumber":32},{"month":"2017-02","randomNumber":12}} is not a valid structure. You need to use a list and append/update element to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have already created a dictionary of a dictionary.

```
{"key1":{"month":"2017-01","randomNumber":32}}
```

The above is a `dict` with key `key1` whose value is also a `dict`.

What you need is to create a `list` of `dict` & append the new `dict` to that list. Following is the example.

```
>>> a = dict(q=1,w=[dict(e=3)])
>>> a
{'q': 1, 'w': [{'e': 3}]}
>>> a.get('w')
[{'e': 3}]
>>> a.get('w').append(dict(r=4))
>>> a
{'q': 1, 'w': [{'e': 3}, {'r': 4}]}
>>> a.get('w').append(dict(e=4))
>>> a
{'q': 1, 'w': [{'e': 3}, {'r': 4}, {'e': 4}]}
>>>
```